# SOA Project vs Service Bus Project

Tags: soa, servicebus, bpel, oracle-soa

I’ve been learning a little bit about SOA and Oracle SOA Suite 12c, I barely understand that I can use BPEL Process in a SOA Project and that I cannot use it with Service Bus Project and that SOA Composites are deployed into the Oracle Enterprise Manager, while Service Bus Projects are deployed directly to the Oracle Service Bus.

My question is, does anyone know what are the differences between use SOA Projects and Service Bus Project even if I can consume services or use DBAdapter from any?

Is there any good reason to consume my soap, rest, dBadapters, etc in a BPEL Process in the SOA Project instead of doing it directly in my Service Bus Project?

Thanks in advance for you help,

:)

Comment: Removing the **oracle** tag as it is used only for oracle database related questions.

Answer (score 1):

OSB is generally used whenever your flow is simple and light weight like- just DB call, web service call, message routing with few mappings. It can used as a proxy service (to hide the actual implementation) to the external system who is calling this proxy as a web service.

Whereas, SOA is preferred where the flow is complex with bulk transformation or heavy orchestration involving multiple intermediate calls to third party systems, etc.

You can go through the below link to get more information,

https://community.oracle.com/thread/1077167?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: In addition, BPEL it's more suitable to manage sync and async processes, parallel executions and orchestration.